# execute script with user password after login (linux/gnome)

Tags: linux, gnome, pam

I got an idea to use users password and a local key to decrypt a dm-crypt partition with user home directory (and to mount it as a home).

But here is a problem: how can I get such script to be executed? It should be executed after successful authorization but before actual login, and it should have access to freshly inputted password.

Does someone know where to put such script?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem with a simple solution -- you use pam module. 
Here is one example:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login